# Maximize $P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

For $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers that satisfy $xy+yz+xz=1$. Maximize $$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^{2}}}.$$

---

I think if we let $x=\tan A;y=\tan B;z=\tan C$, then

$$P\Leftrightarrow \displaystyle \text {sin}A+\text {sin}B+ \text{sin}C\leq \frac{3}{2}. \hspace{2cm}(1)$$

But I can't prove $(1)$.

Comment: $P$ and your constraint is symmetric with interchange of $x \leftrightarrow y \leftrightarrow z$.  So...  assuming the final solution is also so symmetric, what simplification can you make?

Comment: @David. Your comment that  P(x,y,z) and the constraint are invariant under any permutation of (x,y,z) seems to be a strong argument for $ x_m = y_m = z_m$. ( m stands for maximum) I cannot prove it, once this is established the problem is solved. Can anyone prove it, or am I wrong altogether?

Comment: @PeterSzilas:  You can use Lie group theory and invariants to prove that if the problem respects an invariance, the solution will as well.  Practically, find the solution for $x = y = z$ and then verify that it is optimum, as Michael Rozenberg does, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ we get a value $\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+xy+xz+yz}}\leq\frac{3\sqrt3}{2\sqrt{xy+xz+yz}}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x+y}\leq\frac{3\sqrt{3(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)}}{2\sqrt{xy+xz+yz}}.$$
But by C-S $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x+y}\right)^2\leq(1+1+1)\sum_{cyc}(x+y)=6(x+y+z).$$

Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sqrt{6(x+y+z)}\leq\frac{3\sqrt{3(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)}}{2\sqrt{xy+xz+yz}}$$ or
$$9(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\geq8(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Very nice solution. I checked the following $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}\ge 2,$$and it is true.

Comment: Yes, it's true and easy.

Comment: Did you use Holder ?

Comment: No. Squaring and C-S.

Comment: The following is also true $$\frac{3\sqrt{15}}{5}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2a^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2c^2+1}}\ge 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You're making a mistake.

You have to prove this 
$$
\cos A + \cos B + \cos C \le \frac{3}{2}
$$
because :
$$
1+\tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta
$$

Comment: Okay but now how will you prove this?

Comment: $\cos C = \cos (A+B)$  Try this.

Comment: Wait. Sorry. It's $\cos C = -\cos (A+B)$

Comment: The suggested transformations $x=\tan A$, etc. do not work here. The substitutions are $x=\cot A$, etc.

Comment: Where is it given that $A,B,C$ are angles of a triangle?

Comment: You made them the angles of a triangle when you set $$\tan A \tan B + \tan B \tan C + \tan A \tan C = 1$$. This is true only if $$A+B+C=\pi$$.

Comment: @BobJones Those transformations do not work here because they do not satisfy : $xy+yz+xz=1$

Comment: What? If $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}{3}$, does $\tan A$, etc. satisfy that equality? Try it. The identity $\tan A$, etc. satisfy is $xyz=x+y+z$.

Comment: @BobJones Oh... my bad. Yeah. They satisfy :$$\tan \frac{A}{2}\tan \frac{B}{2}+\tan \frac{B}{2}\tan \frac{C}{2}+\tan \frac{A}{2}\tan \frac{C}{2}=1$$. Yeah. So the $\cot $ transformation ought to work.

Answer (score 1):

Like [How to show that the triangle is equilateral triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574166/how-to-show-that-the-triangle-is-equilateral-triangle),

$\cot A\cot B+\cot B\cot C+\cot C\cot A=1$  with $A+B+C=\pi$

Now use [this](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/demonstrate-that-triangle-abc-sina-sinb-sinc-lt-3-180145)